# insert into two tables using a custom POST api

Tags: node.js, api, model, insert, loopbackjs

using loopback remote method to create a custom api to insert into 2 different tables related with a foreign key located in `photoscomedien` which is `id_comedien` so when testing with the explorer i am able only to insert only in one table because i have only one callback where i can put only one of the 2 queries. i am wondering if there is a way to execute both queries so that the insertion goes to both tables at the same time.

this what i have done already in `cm_comediens.js`

```
'use strict';
  var app = require('../../server/server.js');

  module.exports = function(cm_comediens) {

    cm_comediens.profile = function (idComedien,path,name,id_utilisateur,naissance_date,infos_news_timestamp,timestamp_creation,cb) {

        var ds = app.datasources.mydb;
        var sql = "INSERT INTO cm_comediens (id_comedien,id_utilisateur,naissance_date,infos_news_timestamp,timestamp_creation) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        var sql2 = "INSERT INTO photoscomedien (id_comedien,path,name) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        ds.connector.execute(sql2, [idComedien,path,name], function (err, cm_comedienss) {
            ds.connector.execute(sql, [idComedien,id_utilisateur,naissance_date,infos_news_timestamp,timestamp_creation], function (err, cm_comedienss) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            cb(err, cm_comedienss);        
        });
        });
    };

    cm_comediens.remoteMethod(
        'profile',
        {
            http: { verb: 'post' },
            description: 'Post list of comediens',
             accepts:[
             { arg: 'idComedien', type: 'number' },
             { arg: 'id_utilisateur', type: 'number' },  
             { arg: 'infos_news_timestamp', type: 'date' },  
             { arg: 'naissance_date', type: 'date' },  
             { arg: 'timestamp_creation', type: 'date' } , 
             { arg: 'path', type: 'string' },  
             { arg: 'name', type: 'string' } 
            ],
            returns: { arg: 'data', type: ['cm_comediens'], root: true }
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sequencing queries properly with nested callbacks. The second query is invoked from the first query's completion callback, and that's as it should be.

But you are attempting to insert into `photoscomedien` before you insert into `cm_comediens`.  Reverse the order of your two queries.

You might be wise to **check for errors before** your `.execute() ...` operation inside your callback. If you get an err value, you should report it and not perform the next operation.

Pro tip: learn about, and use, Promises or async/await. Better than infinitely nested callbacks.